# You have to face the consequences of your actions; good or bad (AmE)

Tags: sentence-request

There is a proverb in my language which says: "You have to face the consequences of your actions; good or bad." I was wondering if someone could let me know if the following proverbs sound natural to indicate the same concept. If not, then I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what shall I say to make the best sense (using a common proverb) in AmE:

> - They that dance must pay the fiddler.
> - As you make your bed you must lie on it.

Answer (score 1):

I like this idiom:

> face the music

You say this when you must confront the unpleasant consequences of your actions. For more example, fallow this [link](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/face+the+music).

Another idiom that sounds somewhat similar to your first example would be:

> pay the piper

It basically means the same thing as *face the music*.